# Is it allowed for a guru to wear western clothing?

Tags: guru, allowed

All the Hindu gurus I have seen wear some clothes that are indian. Clothes like [*kurta*](https://images.app.goo.gl/REWN2SrWqTKCtwaBA), [*dhoti*](https://images.app.goo.gl/He5jwauReBK25DrL7),and other **Indian** clothes. 
I have never seen one wearing a [coat pant](https://images.app.goo.gl/E3TeF6xWQD2tVwWJA).

So can a guru wear [western clothing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_wear)?

**Edit**

*Note: the currently posted [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45840/22556) cites Vivekananda and argues that the dress of a guru or any other person shouldn't be the focus of spirituality, however, I'm looking for a scripture-based answer on the kind of attire a spiritual guru/master should be wearing*

Comment: Why did you accept the answer posted below when it doesn't answer your question?

Comment: @sv. Actually the answer partially answers my question but the last comment answers my question. You can see the link.

Comment: Yes, I know the comment partly answers your question but it's still a comment, isn't it? The answer posted is simply saying, it doesn't matter. It says the same thing about 'food' also, so, imagine someone asking 'can a guru consume meat?' and the same thing is posted as an answer - is that a valid answer? I think you are accepting answers too early. IMO, the accepted answer looks like commentary on your question, not really addressing the central question.

Comment: @sv. Well you are correct. The answer itself didn't answer my question but it was the comment that answered my question.

Comment: @sv. Anyway can you answer my question

Comment: If you've already accepted an unsatisfactory answer, there's no incentive for others to answer again...that's why I suggested not to accept answers too soon.

Comment: @sv. Okay, how can I get a good answer. Should I unaccepte the answer I previously accepted

Comment: 'how can I get a good answer' - if you feel that's not the kind of answer you were expecting, first un-accept the answer. Then edit your question and say, "Note: the currently posted [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45840) cites Vivekananda and argues that the dress of a guru or any other person shouldn't be the focus of spirituality, however, I'm looking for a scripture-based answer on the kind of attire a spiritual guru/master should be wearing" and later flag the answer as NAA (not an answer). If you still don't get a good answer, you can offer bounty with the same explanation.

Comment: @sv. Thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 7):

I appolozize for my answer is going to be in little tough tone.

> And even in religion, special field, there came the most horrible
> degradations. What can you expect of a race which for hundreds of
> years has been busy in discussing such momentous problems as whether
> we should drink a glass of water with the right hand or the left? What
> more degradation can there be than that the greatest minds of a
> country have been discussing about the kitchen for several hundreds of
> years, discussing whether I may touch you or you touch me, and what is
> the penance for this touching! **The themes of the Vedanta, the
> sublimest and the most glorious conceptions of God and soul ever
> preached on earth, were half-lost**, buried in the forests, preserved
> by a few Sannyâsins, w**hile the rest of the nation discussed the
> momentous questions** of touching each other, and **dress**, and food.
> (The Work Before Us, Lectures from Colombo to Almora, Complete Works
> of Swami Vivekananda Vol 3 )

No, decisions about what clothing you wear aren't spiritually important.

Comment: It doesn't answer my question. It is about guru and clothes

Comment: That's exactly my answer. Its not a momentous question @DarkKnight

Comment: The qoute you mentioned doesn't talk about guru and Brahmins. It talks about normal people

Comment: Anyway can a guru wear western clothing. Like cout suit

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/in/rami-sivan-091b1a1a/?originalSubdomain=au
A great Hindu Guru who did wear western clothing
My answer was to tell you these kind of questions arent important for spiritual practice. Sorry if it offended you @DarkKnight

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link

Comment: Not a Hindu, but I've submitted an edit to explicitly state the answer you've left implied in the quote.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note something - the clothes and often robe like materials worn by Gurus usually has nothing to do with spirituality itself, but is traditionally due to the fact that such clothing is the most comfortable to meditate in for extended periods of time. Likewise in certain cases robes are worn simply because they are cheaper than modern clothes, and acts as a sign of modesty - however obviously not all Gurus follow that modesty aspect, as some such clothing are extremely extravagant looking.

Suits /  coatpants are usually far less comfortable than any kind of robe or casual material, as a general rule - due to how they often constrain motion in some way, even if tailored. Plus, also remember that "western culture" didn't really exist during times when most authoritative texts were written. Even modern "shirts" don't really go back that far.